# Storing data from MySQL into multi-dimensional array?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, swing, netbeans

I am trying to store data which is called from MySQL database table where the data will be based on a specific user number. I have set the connection using a `PreparedStatement` and a `ResultSet`. With using a `while loop`, I need to call up the data from the database and store it in this array. Once stored, I need to call up this data in the array to be displayed in text fields on the interface.

Here is the coding:

```
public static void find(int x)
{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","root","root");

            PreparedStatement stmt=conn.PrepareStatement("Select * from employee where userNum ='" + x +"'");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
          while(rs.next())
          {

          }
```

I am trying to put some statements inside of the `while loop` in order to display the data from the array to the interface.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. But start by learning about prepared statements, and using them. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and will fail if x ever contains a single quote.

Comment: How to do it? What statements do I need to put in the array and how to display it on the interface?

Comment: @JBNizet I have looked over the document in the link that you posted, and it does not touch on using multi-dimensional arrays at all which is what was clearly specified in my question

Comment: @JBNizet I do appreciate your time looking at this question, but I would just like to point out that the other person who responded to my question, understood it and answered it perfectly without problems or saying there was no question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using string concatenation to get the x value into the query, put a `?` in the string and then use the `setInt(1, x)` function to set the value to be substituted for the query. Indexing starts with 1.

Making the result set `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` is necessary for using `first()` after going through the list just to get the row count to initialize the 2D array. It would probably be better to get specific types for each column instead of just treating everything as an object. But if it is useful it can be done.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from employee where userNum=?",
        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE
);
stmt.setInt(1, x);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
List l = new ArrayList();
rs.first();
int rowcount = 0;
do {
    rowcount++;
} while (rs.next());
rs.first();
int rowindex = 0;
Object array2D[][] = new Object[rowcount][];
do {
    array2D[rowindex] = new Object[numberOfColumns];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
        array2D[rowindex][i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
    }
    // prints each row on separate line
    System.out.println("array2D[" + rowindex + "] = " + Arrays.toString(array2D[rowindex])); 
    rowindex++;
} while (rs.next());
System.out.println("array2D = " + Arrays.deepToString(array2D));
```

Comment: I just tried your coding and it is very close to working. I should have specified that the interface will display information such as first name, last name and age of a person. There is a text field for each of these fields. How can we manipulate your coding so that txtFName displays the first name, txtLName displays the last name and txtAge displays the age. We managed to get it to display all in one text field using the very last line of code in your answer

Comment: it sounds like all you need is one more line of code inside the while loop to print out each row separately.  check updated answer

Comment: I tried the updated answer but it's still not exactly what I am looking for. I have a swing interface with three textfields on it (txtFName, txtlastName, txtAge). Your coding still presents the information in one line. I need each textfield to display the relevant information (first name, last name and age). As I mentioned earlier your coding is extremely close to what I a looking to do but not quite 100% yet. But I need to call the data from the database and store it in the array before displaying it on the interface. I honestly don't get the logic behind that but that is what was requested

Comment: By display I thought you just meant print to a console/terminal. The problem with JTextField is that they only display a single line of text at a time. If you knew that the first name collumn was the first column you could put the firstname of the person on the first row in txtFName with txtFname.setText(array2D[0][0].toString()) but it wouldn't be clear what to do with a person on the second row. A JTable would be a much more natural fit for displaying this kind of data. You could also just append all the text that would have been printed to the console to a JTextArea.

Comment: Thank you so much that got it working :D. I really do appreciate the time and effort you put into helping me with this issue. One more issue, when I try to disconnect from the server I get the following error message: 'java.sql.SQLException: illegal operation on empty result set.' what would be the best way to work around this so that when I disconnect from the database this message does not come up

Comment: Don't worry about that error message, I got it sorted out, thanks :)